# Opening a PDF file in another window with VueJS

Tags: pdf, vue.js, vuejs2

In my previous Angular app I was able to open my resume in another window like such:

```
<a class="link popup" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascipt:window.open('./../../assets/Resume_Christopher_Kade.pdf');">Resume</a>
```

While rewriting my website with Vue, I noted that it did not work as intended, after changing it to:

```
<a class="link popup" href="javascript:void(0);" v-on:click="openPdf()">Resume</a>
```

With `openPdf()` in my component's methods:

```
openPdf () {
    javascipt:window.open('./../assets/Resume_Christopher_Kade.pdf');
}
```

When clicking the link, a new page opens to the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/assets/Resume_Christopher_Kade.pdf
```

while showing an empty route on my screen instead of displaying the pdf in the browser's pdf viewer.

This issue might be related to the way I handle routes in Vue:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [    
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/work',
      name: 'Work',
      component: Work
    },
    {
      path: '/posts',
      name: 'Posts',
      component: Posts
    },
    { path: '*', component: Home }
  ]
})
```

Why isn't it as straightforward as in Angular? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can be your webserver configuration, eg.: `if file exist`

Answer (score 5):

Did you figure it out?

My solution is for projects created with Vue CLI 3 running locally (I haven't built my project yet).

My issue was similar to yours. I just wanted `<a>` link that opened up my pdf file on a new tab but my url concatenated a single hash to my path and redirected me to my home page. And it was a surprisingly easy fix:

```
<a href="./resume.pdf" target="_blank">resume</a>
```

Just a dot, forward slash, and my file name. And my file is located under root > public folder.

> Relative Path Imports
>
> When you reference a static asset using relative path (must start with
>   .) inside JavaScript, CSS or *.vue files, the asset will be included
>   into webpack's dependency graph...
>
> https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports

Comment: It didn't work because my file (a link actually) didn't have `.pdf` extension. Fixed.

Comment: Not working. Still getting the same problem as the question says. It always redirects to localhost://assets/filename.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have `static` folder generated by default by Vue CLI you can simply put the PDF there and do it as follows `<a href="./../static/file.pdf" target="_blank">`.