# VueJS : open a PDF file using the default player in navigator

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, pdf, vuejs2

I'm trying to open a PDF file using VueJS.
I want to open it in a new tab using the default navigator's player.

I've tried the following :

## 1

```
<a href="./pdf/doc.pdf" target="_blank">pdf</a>
```

Where /pdf/doc.pdf is located inside the public directory.
That solution try to open a route adding /pdf/doc.pdf. Not expected and cannot visualize the PDF doc.

## 2

```
<a href="<%= BASE_URL %>/pdf/doc.pdf" target="_blank">pdf</a>
```

I got this error :

> URIError: Failed to decode param '/fr/%3C%=%20BASE_URL%20%%3E/pdf/doc.pdf'

## 3

```
<a @click.prevent="pdfDoc">pdf</a>

data() {
  return {
    pdfDoc: require('../../public/pdf/doc.pdf')
  }
}
```

I got this error :

> ./public/pdf/doc.pdf 1:0
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

How can I simply implement a  to open a PDF in a new tab and display it ?

Comment: This seems to be resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517942/opening-a-pdf-file-in-another-window-with-vuejs

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I was using the same recommendation provided by this link, read my own answer bellow, I found out the issue !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the issue resolved in router config...

```
  {
    path: '*',
    redirect() {
      return Trans.getUserSupportedLang()
    }
  }
```

Caught the request and try to serve the link as a route...
Removing that route works fine in localhost.

Still, on a web hosting it works perfectly fine with that last route.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the PDF doc in your static directory of Vue Project
2. Put the PDF doc outsite the project, and set a Load balance to serve PDF url request